# Numpy: multiply slices of final dimension by another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `x` of dimension `(N, M)` and an array `y` of dimension `(N, M, 2)`. For any `i, j` I would like to multiply each `y[i, j, :]` by `x[i, j]`. How can I do this?

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100, 10)
y = np.random.randn(100, 10, 2)
x * y # this does not work
```

Comment: new leading dimensions are automatic.  Trailing ones have to be added explicitly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add extra dim as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100, 10)
print(x[..., None].shape)
y = np.random.randn(100, 10, 2)
x[..., None] * y
```